# Duplicate exception and warning in separate file with log4j

Tags: java, log4j

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=sip.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t %c - %m%n
```

Above is my log4j configuration. How to duplicate all exceptions and warning in separate log file? I would like to avoid code mofidications

Answer (score 0):

Just add another logger like "R2".

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R, R2
...
log4j.appender.R2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R2.File=sip2.log

log4j.appender.R2.Threshold=WARN
...
```